# Update Angular from any version to latest stable

Tags: angular

I have worked on few projects where I used `angular-cli` which was configured to create apps, components, services, etc. in rc4 release. Now I'd like to update these project to the final release of angular 2 (or latest), what are the steps I need to do to update it correctly?

Is it better to update it version by version until I reach desired release (so first update it to rc5, check if everything works, then rc6, and so on...) or can update it straight to the latest release?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to update to 2.0.0 Final while you're at it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to [angular 2 changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and search for "breaking changes". Each breaking changes section explains how to migrate. Start from rc5 and work your way up.

Answer (score 0):

I completly agree with Luiz's answer, but I found an easier solution, as the project I've been working on isn't that big. The easiest way for me was to upgrade my `angular-cli` to the version 1.0.0-beta.15, which generates everything for Angular 2 Final Release (2.0.0). I began with new project, created same components and just copied code from my older ones.

The project needed some editing, but in 'core' files mostly, so components, services and interfaces were good to go after I copied them.